# html/css positioning issue in ie7/8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this aligned correctly in IE7/8..

If you look at the site in Firefox 4+ it works fine! Not sure if that is the right thing or not..

At the top where the "Sign In" link is; in firefox is exactly how I want it but in IE it is displayed all weird.

If anyone could help, that'd be great. (the site isn't fully functional yet.. still working on it.. thanks!)

Comment: your page contains **23 errors**, fix them first, and the try to fix the IE7/8 errors. (if there are any)
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.thesnugg.com/test.aspx&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, before any attempt to debug CSS is made, you must always validate your page.

You have [23 Errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thesnugg.com%2Ftest.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) at this time, and they are pretty important (but easy to fix) ones. You have unclosed divs, paragraphs, etc. It may be just a couple of errors that are causing a cascade.

My advice: Fix those errors. Start at the first one and work your way down until they all are gone. You are likely to see IE problems disappear. The other browsers are just being more forgiving.

Conditional comments *are* an option for when you're really stuck, but 99% of the time you don't truly need it. Often IE errors are caused by mistakes that other browsers are nice enough to deal with in a graceful manner.

Once upon a time I used to design ***IN*** Internet Explorer, and found that checking my work in FF or Chrome was almost always in line with IE's rendering. Sometimes the newer browsers are too forgiving of errors so you don't catch them.

Answer (score 0):

In your html you  can use special css just for ie so other browsers just ignore:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
 your css here

</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: also you should get in the habit of closing every tag you open, especially the self closing tags like `<input type... />`

Answer (score -1):

you could just create another styling section for IE using *+ hack. IE:

```
*+.signin{
 .....
}
```

Comment: Oh and I didn't try to validate your page, but as @Wesly Murch said, fix those errors first in case it is your errors causing the problem or other problems.

Comment: IE Hacks is not a recommended practice any more ... It's 2011 :) Write a valid code and use conditional styling

Comment: @Ahmad you're right. But sometimes I find it useful for certain situations where it's much easier than banging my head for hours ;)

Comment: Oh, and might I add, you say its 2011, but CSS3 brings along still some new hacks @font-face namely for the moment, so no matter what year you're talking, there will always be hacks to get certain things done. It's not that bad so long as you don't go hacking all over the place IMO.

Comment: @Ahmad: IE hacks have their place, Father CSS™ isn't going to come bashing down your door because you have invalid (but working) CSS code to target IE. Writing a whole separate stylesheet is overkill for 2 or 3 fixes (IMHO) and is a lot harder to maintain. It may be 2011 but there's still a lot of 2008 browsers around. And besides, it never was a "recommended practice"